# Extract using CHARINDEX while Casting or Converting in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, charindex

I'm using SQL Server 2008.
With the below code that someone here helped me with, is it possible to cast or convert column2 from varchar(50) to numeric(10,0) within the same select statement? This is part of a stored procedure that imports a tabbed delimited text file. If I can't do this in the select, I'll probably create some intermediate temp tables. Thanks for any help.

```
SELECT column1
 , RIGHT(column2,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(column2))-1) as extracted
 , column3 
FROM myTable
```

Someone asked for sample data. column2 could have Bluebird Clinic-333 as a varchar. The result of the query would be 333 as a numeric. The question has already been answered, but I added that in case someone finds it helpful.

Comment: Do you mean `column2` field or 2nd column of the query output?

Comment: The result will be inserted into another table as numeric. Either way might work - but definitely the query output.

Comment: Could you add some sample values foe those columns ?

Comment: I added a sample value for column2 even though the question was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe?

```
SELECT column1
 , CAST(RIGHT(column2,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(column2))-1) AS numeric(10,0)) as extracted
 , column3 
FROM myTable
```